# Android 1.5 sdk Android Virtual Device emulator errors Java Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi so I am working through this book called Beginning Android Games because and I am having some problems with the Android 1.5 Android Virtual Device.

First the SDK for Eclipse (the program I am using) didnt have the 1.5 SDK for Android so I had it installed when you first try to run a AVD it asks has a checklist of SDK's that will be fetched and installed for you if you check the box. I did this, had the 1.5 SDK installed however when i try to run a AVD emulator using the 1.5 sdk i get a

(Failed to allocate memory: 8 This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. please contact the application's support team for more information.)

type of error. But when I used the default 4.2 SDK for an AVD emulator the emulator showed up. I dont get what im doing wrong here.

Also in eclipse i have the Android ADT and SDK installed. In eclipse when i click on window then Android virtual device manager and I try to start a new emulator the 1.5 sdk i installed doesnt show. But when I click on window->sdk manager->tools->manage avds then my 1.5 sdk shows up and I can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem was in the amount of ram  for the virtual machine.**

This following solution worked for me. In the following configuration file:

```
C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\<avd-profile-name>.avd\config.ini
```

**Replace**

hw.ramSize=1024

by

hw.ramSize=1024MB

Comment: This got my emulator to run thanks but everytime i try to create a new emulator for each one i have to go back into my files and fix that MB error so is there a more permanent solution so i wont have to do that everytime?

Answer (score -1):

Go to Help -> Check for updates if there it shows some updates needed, then you can install them. May be it will work.